# How can I create a new column in Oracle SQL, which is based on the subtraction of two other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL , I have two date columns .

I want to create a new column , which subtracts the first date from the second date.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried to refer to the columns by position, like so :

```
10 - 5 AS "Aver. Security Duration"
```

But it simply subtracts 10 - 5.

thanks!

Comment: well, you should use the actual column names

Comment: Are you looking for a calculated column to always be present in the table, or simply to do this on a single query?

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades - I'd like to have a calculated column which is  always  present in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a virtual column (one which is automatically computed for each row) in the following manner:

```
ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE
  ADD (VIRTUAL_COLUMN_NAME AS (SOME_DATE - SOME_OTHER_DATE));
```

[Example here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#BABIDDJJ)

Comment: we can do same by creating a view over the table.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one :

it is

```
hur.LAST_UPDATE_DATE - hur.end_date AS "Avg Dur"
```